# couldn't run the TestProgram of JProfiler offline sample

Tags: api, offline, jprofiler

all

I met an error when I running the sample of JProfiler7 offline on my windows PC , the code is from "jprofiler7\api\samples\offline\src\TestProgram.java" ,and got the message as thus:

> JProfiler> A different instance of the native library has been
>
> JProfiler> loaded. Please check the appropriate environment
>
> JProfiler> variable. (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)
>
> JProfiler> Exiting.

I'm sure there is no any JProfiler process running, and I've imported the referenced libraries by "agent.jar" and set my PATH of JProfiler：

> C:\Users\user>echo %PATH%
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows-x64;C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin;

**I wanna use the JProfiler API for remoting doing something ,could anybody know how to fix that?**

JProfiler:7.2.3
Windows: Win7 Enterprise SP1
JDK:1.6.0_33

And if I use the arguments as following:

```
-agentlib:jprofilerti=offline,id=4321,config=C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\config\config.xml "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\agent.jar"
```

there will be another message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jprofiler/agent/ControllerImpl
    at com.jprofiler.api.agent.Controller.startCPURecording(Controller.java:87)
    at TestProgram.main(TestProgram.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jprofiler.agent.ControllerImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 2 more
```

**____________edited 2014.05.08 17:04  CST__________________________________**

I tried to run the demo of platform  (jprofiler7\api\samples\platform\src-profiler\TestProfiler.java) , got the same message both without args and with args(-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=offline,id=112,config="C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\config\config.xml -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\agent.jar):

```
    JProfiler> A different instance of the native library has been
JProfiler> loaded. Please check the appropriate environment
JProfiler> variable. (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)
JProfiler> Exiting.
```

———————————————————ending—————————————————————————————————————————————
solved that.
In my way, firstly, I start a Java application with VM args

```
"-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849"
```

Then I run a JProfiler platfrom program with args :

```
-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=offline,id=112,config="C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\config\config.xml -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\agent.jar
```

then I could catch some information , with null value.

```
Profiling data :
Memory data:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jprofiler.core.comm.d.a.getTotalHeapUsage(ejt:100)
    at TestProfiler.dumpMemoryData(TestProfiler.java:82)
    at TestProfiler.dumpProfilingData(TestProfiler.java:55)
    at TestProfiler.main(TestProfiler.java:47)
```

In a word , it could run...so ending the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the -agentlib VM parameter with

-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=offline,...

and remove the -Xbootclasspath VM parameter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to replace the -agentlib and remove the -Xbootclasspath as you wrote, but , I got the error message "JProfiler> A different instance of the native library has been
JProfiler> loaded. Please check the appropriate environment
JProfiler> variable. (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)
JProfiler> Exiting."  again.

Comment: I wanna do something without JProfiler GUI , for example , I want to call the JProfiler API to save a snapshot and so on... so I need do via the offline mode. [link](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/offline.html) ,and the arguments is following as thus , similar as the webpage "-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=offline,id=112,config="C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\config\config.xml -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\agent.jar"

Comment: Someone told me try to hold a connection first ,so I'm falling into the Class "com.jprofiler.api.platform" . what's in your opinion ?Was I missing anything...

Comment: the webpage is [offline html](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/offline.html)

Comment: Check your PATH environment variable, you have an older version of jprofilerti.dll somewhere on the path. The platform API does not seem applicable here, just use the offline mode.

Comment: Sorry, I've searched my computer disk, there only one copy of "jprofilerti.dll", and there is no chance to support an old version, the system path showed upon...and I'm seeking how to fix the error message. `JProfiler> A different instance of the native library has been JProfiler> loaded. Please check the appropriate environment JProfiler> variable. (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) JProfiler> Exiting.`

Comment: Thanks , it may be cause by my wrong start way...even though i didn't catch any data yet, that's another thing.